# Is there a way to get the return value of the overloaded operator-> rather than its member value?

Tags: c++

Let's say I have a class with an overloaded operator-> which returns a pointer. However, the usage of -> requires member after it, but can I not provide the member? Is there a way to get the return value directly?

Here is a code snippet to demonstrate my question: I am wondering if there is a way to get the value of `ptr` from `Wrapper` class through the `operator->`?

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Entry{
    // could have other private fields, so `a` may not be the head of Entry.
    int a;
    int b;
};

class Wrapper {
public:
    Wrapper(Entry* p): ptr(p) {}
    
    Entry* operator->() {
        return ptr;
    }
    
    
private:
    Entry* ptr;
};


int main()
{
    Entry entry {12, 34};
    Wrapper wrapper(&entry);
    cout << wrapper->a << "\n";
    
    // is there a way to get wrapper->ptr from the operator-> directly?
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes there is.  You can simply do, for example:

```
cout << wrapper.operator->();
```

Answer (score 3):

It is customary in this situation to provide another method to get the pointer you want, eg

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Entry{
    // could have other private fields, so `a` may not be the head of Entry.
    int a;
    int b;
};

class Wrapper {
public:
    Wrapper(Entry* p): ptr(p) {}
    
    Entry* operator->() {
        return ptr;
    }
    
    Entry* get() {
        return ptr;
    }
  
private:
    Entry* ptr;
};


int main()
{
    Entry entry {12, 34};
    Wrapper wrapper(&entry);
    cout << wrapper->a << "\n";    
    cout << wrapper.get() << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is just an example, but the "Wrapper" may be written by others, for example, an iterator of a map.